# Executing multiple SPs containing BEGIN TRANS - COMMIT TRANS using TransactionScope

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, transactionscope

What happens when BEGIN TRANS - COMMIT TRANS is done in one SP and Multiple SPs are executed in TransactionScope and error is thrown before completing scope.

So pseudo code is as follows

```
//Using TransactionScope() {
//   executing SP1 
//   executing SP2
//   executing SP3
//   throw new Exception();
//}
```

SP2 contains code as below.

```
// BEGIN TRANS
//   Update Statement1
//   Update Statement2
//   Update Statement3
// COMMIT TRANS
```

What will happen if we assume that transaction gets committed in SP2?

1. Everything gets rolled back
2. 3 statements in SP2 gets committed. Everything else gets rolled back?

I don't know if it matters or not but just in case, all the three SPs are executed using one connection object and the connection is getting closed and opened again between two ExecuteNonQuery statements.

Comment: In case if an error occurs in any of the SP's the transaction will be rolled back . If SP2 gets committed but SP3 throws an error , no update will takes place and the whole transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: @praveen why didn't you posted it as answer?

Comment: That was my mistake .Anyways if my answer helped u in any way ,i will be more pleased

Answer (score 2):

There is only one transaction, always, the outermost transaction started by the outermost transaction scope. All the other inner transaction scopes and all the other BEGIN TRANSACTION in T-SQL code occuring under the outermost transaction scope are nothing but glorified increments of [`@@TRANCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx) and all those COMMITS are nothing but decrements of the same. Is only the last COMMIT that matter, until then the transaction has not committed.

So in your example the SP2 did not commit anything. All it did it incremented @@TRANCOUNT to 2 and then decremented it back to 1. The transaction is still active, and when the C# code throws the transaction is rolled back.

As a side note see [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for a template of how to write good exception safe stored procedures.

Comment: It was accepted already, then I unaccepted it so that anyone else intending to answer can also post answer or up-vote your answer. Otherwise others might think that its answered and that they don't need to visit it. I will still wait for others to up-vote your answer and then accept it in a day or two. Though, looking at your reputation, I'm sure that you won't provide wrong/misleading info at the least.